# Is an Apple OS airdrop bot possible?

Tags: ios, swift, api, bots, airdrop

Is it possible to create an Airdrop bot that sends a picture automatically to nearby Apple devices?
Like I choose the picture, turn on the bot, and go to a public space. While the bot is doing its thing.

Is there an Api out there or open source code?

I looked on google, but telegram bots for the crypto space were the main results.

Comment: To my knowledge, I think that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in theory something like this is possible with enough money to find people to build the technology and components for it, however, practically, I do not think this project is achievable. This may be tunnel vision and if you can find a way to do such a thing, all power to you!

I however, do not think that this can be done.